# How to listen to events from event grid listener in azure to bucket in gcp

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions, webhooks

I want to capture events from event grid listener from Azure to buckets in gcp. I am creating a google cloud function in GCP using node js and providing its URL in the webhook end point in event grid subscription in Azure. I wrote below code:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
var bucket = storage.bucket('sample-buck17');
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.bucket.status(200).send(message);
};
```

It throws an error saying as unknown resource type. Can anyone help me in capturing events from azure to gcp using node js. Where am I going wrong. I am new to this environment.

Comment: where do you get the error ? are you able to capture the event triggered in the gcp function ?

Comment: No can you help me with that. I couldn't find any relevant link for this

Comment: You can either use Event grid triggers or web hook to a http endpoint. It has to be validated first. check this post. The http handling part will be in your GCP function . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events